# How can I automatically change the value of a Boolean field?

Tags: django, forms, post, boolean

This particular Boolean field determines whether a post is a draft. The default is set to True.

When the user edits a draft, I want the value to be automatically changed to False, so that it is listed with all the other posts (instead of in the drafts list).

Could the submit button both submit the post and change the Boolean value? Ideally, I suppose, the field would be changed as soon as the draft form is entered.

Here is the relevant code:
**Template for editing Draft**

```
{{ title }}</B></h3></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12-md-7 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-8">
        <div class="panel panel default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p class="well col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-12">{{ summary }}</p>

                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% include 'posts/form-template.html' %}
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">

                        <div class="col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This my form for editing the draft**

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title", "content", "categories", "tags",
        ]
```

**This is the Post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = HTMLField()
        draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
        upvote = VotableManager()
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField(
            'category.Category',
            help_text='Categorize this item.'
        )
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(
            'category.Tag',
            help_text='Tag this item.'
        )

        suggest = models.ForeignKey('Suggest', blank=True, null=True, default=0)


        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

**Here is the view for editing the draft**

```
def post_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    model = Post
    form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form,
        "summary": instance.summary,
    }
    return render(request, "posts/suggest_form_update.html", context)
```

Comment: "**Here is the view for editing the draft **" Where is your view??

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Thanks. It is now added.

Comment: What is stopping you doing this yourself in the view? You have the instance, why can't you set draft=False?

Comment: @TomHiggins Daniel is right. You should do it in your views.py file. That is the recommended way.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Prakhar  I feel like an idiot! This works. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just add draft=False in the views.py, right?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Which parameter does that go in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in two ways:

1. In your view (inside the `if form.is_valid():` conditional, before the object is saved.
2. In your form by customising the `save()` method.

   ```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.instance.draft = True
       return super(UpdateForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```